# Django form: Argument must be a string or a number, not 'method'

Tags: python, django, django-forms

When trying to add validation to my form `self.cleaned_data['field']` and `cleaned_data = super(MyForm, self).clean()` both seem to return 'method' variables.

When trying the following validation I encountered `TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'method'`.

Similar errors also appear with no custom validation.

forms.py:

```
class EntryForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Entry
        fields = ['row_control', 'date', 'hours']

    def clean(self):
        clean_data = super(EntryForm, self).clean()

        hours = clean_data.get("hours")

        if float(hours) <= 0.00:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Hours worked must be more than 0.")

        # Always return cleaned data
        return clean_data
```

The DEBUG page shows the local variables on if float(hours) <= 0.00: line to be:

```
__class__   <class 'timesheet.forms.EntryForm'>
hours   <bound method Field.clean of <django.forms.fields.DecimalField object at 0x1066ca668>>
self    <EntryForm bound=True, valid=True, fields=(row_control;date;hours)>
clean_data  {'date': <bound method Field.clean of <django.forms.fields.DateField object at 0x106649fd0>>,'hours': <bound method Field.clean of <django.forms.fields.DecimalField object at 0x1066ca668>>,'row_control': <bound method Field.clean of <django.forms.models.ModelChoiceField object at 0x106804668>>}
```

This is the context it is being used in.

views.py:

```
@login_required
def monthview(request, year, month):

    # Initialise forms
    row_control_form = RowControlForm(initial={'month_control_record': month_control_record})
    entry_form = EntryForm()

    # Making form fields hidden
    entry_form.fields['row_control'].widget = forms.HiddenInput()
    entry_form.fields['date'].widget = forms.HiddenInput()


    row_control_form.fields['month_control_record'].widget = forms.HiddenInput()

    # If user has submitted a form
    if request.method == 'POST':

        # If user submits row_control form
        if 'row_control_submit' in request.POST:

            instance_pk = request.POST["instance"]

            try:
                row_control_form = RowControlForm(request.POST, instance=RowControl.objects.get(pk=instance_pk))
            except ValueError:
                row_control_form = RowControlForm(request.POST)

            if row_control_form.is_valid():
                row_control_form.save()

        elif 'entry_submit' in request.POST:

            instance_pk = request.POST["instance"]

            try:
                entry_form = EntryForm(request.POST, instance=Entry.objects.get(pk=instance_pk))
            except ValueError:
                entry_form = EntryForm(request.POST)

            if entry_form.is_valid():
                entry_form.save()


        return redirect('/' + year + '/' + month + '/')

    if request.is_ajax():
        rawrow = request.GET['row']
        rawday = request.GET['day']

        # Get the employee model for the user signed in
        employee = Employee.objects.get(user=request.user)

        # Get the first day of the month from URL
        first_day_of_month = datetime.date(int(year), int(month), 1)

        # Get the month_control_record for the user logged in and for the month
        month_control_record = MonthControlRecord.objects.get(employee=employee, first_day_of_month=first_day_of_month)

        the_row_control = RowControl.objects.filter(month_control_record=month_control_record);

        if int(rawday) > 0:

            the_row_control = the_row_control[int(rawrow)]

            date = str(year) + '-' + str(month) + '-' + str(rawday)

            try:
                the_entry = Entry.objects.get(row_control=the_row_control, date=date)
                instance = the_entry.pk
                hours = str(the_entry.hours)
            except Entry.DoesNotExist:
                instance = None
                hours = None

            the_row_control = the_row_control.pk

            data = {
                'form': "entry",
                'row_control': the_row_control,
                'date': date,
                'hours': hours,
                'instance': instance,

            }

            data = json.dumps(data)

        else:

            instance = the_row_control[int(rawrow)]

            departments = Department.objects.all()

            departmentno = index_number_of_object(departments, instance.department) + 1

            activites = Activity.objects.all()

            activityno = index_number_of_object(activites, instance.activity) + 1

            notes = instance.notes

            data = {
                'form': "row_control",
                'department': departmentno,
                'activity': activityno,
                'instance': instance.pk,
                'notes': notes,

            }

            print(data)

            data = json.dumps(data)

        return HttpResponse(data)

    context = {
        'row_control_form': row_control_form,
        'entry_form': entry_form,
        'year': year,
        'month': month,
    }

    return render(request, "timesheet/monthview.html", context)
```

template.html:

```
<div class="" id="entry-form-container">
    <form action="{{ request.path }}" class="form-inline" method=
    "post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ entry_form|crispy }}

        <input id="entry_instance" name="instance" type="hidden">

        <button class="btn btn-primary" name="entry_submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
            <i class="fa fa-floppy-o"></i> Save
        </button>

    </form>
</div>
```

EDIT: Removed custom validation and the form is completely failing to validate, removed validation from title.

Comment: `super(EntryForm, self).clean()` is a hook method as per the Django documentation [ModelForm clean](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/forms/modelforms/#overriding-the-clean-method). It does not return anything.
If you want to clean the specific field, you can define a `def clean_hours(self, obj)` method for it.

Comment: @JRajan clean_hours gives me the same error as it returns a method.

Answer (score 1):

Not quite sure what / where I went wrong but this works:

forms.py:

```
class EntryForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Entry
        fields = ['row_control', 'date', 'hours']

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = self.cleaned_data

        if cleaned_data['hours'] <= 0:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Hours worked must be more than 0.")

        # Always return cleaned data
        return cleaned_data
```